# bootstrap datepicker, beforeShowDay and array of disabled dates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use bootstrap datepicker plugin (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/release/docs/index.rst) with array of disabled days passed into it.

My code (partial):

```
 var disabled_dates = ["23.03.2014","21.03.2014"];
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      language: "pl",
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: '+1d',
      weekStart: 1,
      default: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
           var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy', 'pl');
           if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), disabled_dates) != -1){
               return {
                  enabled : false
               };
           }
          return;
      }
  });
```

it works (almost) OK. It disables wrong date. Instead of disabling 23.03.2014 it disabled 24.04.2014.
I am not sure where is the issue, on timezone maybe? Any suggestions?

Comment: Im having the same problem. The accepted answer only works in IE11+ So im still looking for the answer. StartDate is irrelevant.

Comment: I found that this happens because it translates the date to UTC, which will make all dates go a day back in time if you are in our timezone. Don't know how to fix it yet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking inside the plugin, I found out `$.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate` returns a UTC-formatted string instead of GMT. Try changing the setting of **formattedDate** variable to this:

```
var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('pl',{day:'2-digit',year:'numeric',month:'2-digit'});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove line "startDate: '+1d'," it does not make any sense using it when you have available dates array. Anyway, you can add new Date() function to get atual date.

It will be something like this:

```
 //here you store new Date() Object to get today's date formatted as you want dd.mm.yyy

 var disabled_dates = ["23.03.2014","21.03.2014"];
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      language: "pl",
      autoclose: true,
      //removed line: startDate: '+1d',
      weekStart: 1,
      default: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
           var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd.mm.yyyy', 'pl');
           if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), disabled_dates) != -1){
               return {
                  enabled : false
               };
           }
          return;
      }
  });
```