# Javascript date and UTC using Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

similar to this question: [bootstrap datepicker, beforeShowDay and array of disabled dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566009/bootstrap-datepicker-beforeshowday-and-array-of-disabled-dates)

but more specific about my problem with it. beforeShowDay returns a JS date, like:  Sun Jan 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
When i format this date with `$.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd-mm-yyyy', 'nl');` it gets transformed into UTC, which will bring it back to end Jan 24! So i will have wrong date matching.

Code:

```
var disabled_dates = ["25-01-2015"];

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    language: "nl",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: undefined,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'dd-mm-yyyy', 'nl');
      if ( $.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), disabled_dates) != -1 ) {

         return {
           enabled: false
         }

      }
    }
```